# drop_duplicates() got multiple values for argument 'keep'

Tags: python, pandas

I'm getting and error that I haven't been able to resolve that I'm hoping someone can assist with.

The error is; "drop_duplicates() got multiple values for argument 'keep'"

When I execute the following:

```
hardware_df.Tags.str.contains(r'hardware').drop_duplicates('Id',keep='last').count()
```

hardware_df looks like

```
Id      Created at          Tags
3670    2016-04-26 15:42:00 hardware
4497    2016-06-21 16:19:00 software version automation
4501    2016-06-22 14:19:00 hardware_issue hardware_other version
```

Any suggestion as to what I am not seeing?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example if possible.

Comment: You are calling drop_duplicates on a series (`str.contains(r'hardware')` returns a boolean series) so you can't pass a subset (i.e. Id) to that.

Comment: Rookie move! Thanks ayhan.